# DoCmd.ApplyFilter stops working, Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I would like to use 3 text boxes and 3 combo boxes to search a data list. I created a command button to trigger the event. It works, the filter is applied, but only for about 30 minutes. Afterwards, the data is displayed unfiltered. I do not receive any error, it just stops to use the filter.

```
Private Sub Command370_Click()
    DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", "[Ervaring 1].Value Like ""*"" & [Forms]![Werknemers lijst]![cboervaring].value & ""*"" And [Opleiding1].Value Like ""*"" & [Forms]![Werknemers lijst]![combo619].Value & ""*"" And [Taal 1].Value Like ""*"" & [Forms]![Werknemerslijst]![combo621].Value & ""*""", ""
    DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", "[Voornaam] Like ""*"" & [Forms]![Werknemers lijst]![tref1] & ""*"" Or [Achternaam] Like ""*"" & [Forms]![Werknemers lijst]![tref1] & ""*"" Or [Geslacht] Like ""*"" & [Forms]![Werknemers lijst]![tref1] & ""*""", ""
    DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", "[Cedula] Like ""*"" & [Forms]![Werknemers lijst]![tref1] & ""*"" Or [Nationaliteit] Like ""*"" & [Forms]![Werknemers lijst]![tref1] & ""*""", ""
    DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", "[Voornaam] Like ""*"" & [Forms]![Werknemers lijst]![tref2] & ""*"" Or [Achternaam] Like ""*"" & [Forms]![Werknemers lijst]![tref2] & ""*"" Or [Geslacht] Like ""*"" & [Forms]![Werknemers lijst]![tref2] & ""*""", ""
    DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", "[Cedula] Like ""*"" & [Forms]![Werknemers lijst]![tref2] & ""*"" Or [Nationaliteit] Like ""*"" & [Forms]![Werknemers lijst]![tref2] & ""*""", ""
    DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", "[Voornaam] Like ""*"" & [Forms]![Werknemers lijst]![tref3] & ""*"" Or [Achternaam] Like ""*"" & [Forms]![Werknemers lijst]![tref3] & ""*"" Or [Geslacht] Like ""*"" & [Forms]![Werknemers lijst]![tref3] & ""*""", ""
    DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", "[Cedula] Like ""*"" & [Forms]![Werknemers lijst]![tref3] & ""*"" Or [Nationaliteit] Like ""*"" & [Forms]![Werknemers lijst]![tref3] & ""*""", ""
End Sub
```

Comment: In principle it could have just applied the filter and stopped. How do you know it's not working? It's impossible to reproduce the problem without your database, and the purpose of your filter is obscure. Can you make a minimal example with some data? Have you tried to use each of the `ApplyFilter` lines one at a time to see if singularly they work?

Comment: I did try to use each ApplyFilter line by itself, they all perfectly worked. When I entered the code and tried to run it, it filtered exactly in the way that I wanted to. I have created a data list to show all my employees, with the filter I want to be able to search on first name, last name, Cedula, Nationality and gender by using three text boxes and to search on experience, education and languages I have created three combo boxes because these are multi value fields. I am new to this website and not sure how to provide you with an clear example including some data?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. In your case it could be tricky to create a minimum verifiable Access07 DB though. Anyway, a clarification: when you say that the filter "works for 30 min" you mean that after 30 min it starts displaying data unfiltered?

Comment: Exactly and when I delete the whole code, close the database, reopen the database en enter the code line by line again it works again for a few minutes. I am not that experienced with VBA so it might be possible that there is an error in the code or it is to long or something?

Comment: No if it filters the data once it should be able to do it always. I'd rather think that Access refreshes the data in your report, and does not reapply the filter. What happens if after 30 min you press the button again? See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243764%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: When I press the button after a while actually nothing happens besides that the form header flickers.

Comment: `DoCmd.ApplyFilter` doesn't work cumulatively, so your sub can't really work. Only the last filter will be applied.

Comment: Perhaps is better if you extract the results as an explicit query or view? Interactive filtered form: http://www.knowledgewave.com/blog/msoffice/access/create-an-interactive-access-form-to-filter-a-query-by-date-range-2.html ApplyFilter method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197651.aspx (Office >= 2013, but I strongly doubt anything changed)

Comment: @Andre is there a way to make the command work cumulatively?

Comment: No, you'd have to combine all filter expressions into one filter.

Comment: So just use Docmd.ApplyFilter once and then all the filter expressions?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution (instead of using the ApplyFilter method)...

1. Make a query that filters the data the way you want it.
2. Make a copy of your form that uses the filtered query instead of the table.
3. On the main form, have a command button that runs code to close the form and open the filtered version of the form.
4. On the filtered form, have a command button to close that form and open mani form.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not that familiar with queries, so this sounds way more complicated.

Comment: Hmm I would think doing the ApplyFilter command in vba code would be way more complicated than just editing a query. You really should learn to build queries. They are one of the main features of Access.

Comment: @fleur You are already doing a query, very inefficiently. Query=request data from the database. You do it unfiltered, and then you manually apply a filter. You can request the data from the database *already filtered* the way you want. DBs are optimized for that.